# How to show YouTube link via model property using asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called video:

```
public class Video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }       
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string VideoLink { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }    
}
```

And lets say i use a CRUD controller, using the above model, and create a new video with `Title`, `Description`, and `VideoLink`,

[image]

After creation, the URL displays as a text not as a YouTube video.

Comment: Why don't you use `<video>` tag for displaying the video?

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `video` tag:

```
<video src="@item.VideoLink"></video>
```

Update:

> YouTube players can be embedded in a web page using either an 
>   tag or an  tag. By appending parameters to the IFrame or SWF
>   URL, you can customize the playback experience in your application.
>   For example, you can automatically play videos using the autoplay
>   parameter or cause a video to play repeatedly using the loop
>   parameter. You can also use the enablejsapi parameter to enable the
>   player to be controlled via the IFrame Player API. [more info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en)

```
<object width="640" height="390">
                <param name="movie"
                       value="@item.VideoLink"></param>
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="@item.VideoLink"
                       type=" application />x-shockwave-flash"
                       allowscriptaccess="always"
                       width="640" height="390"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, i tried this but im getting small black boxes, am i missing something?

Comment: @john Embedding youtube video is a little bit different, Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: get the markup for embedding a video from [here](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/youtube.php) and then do like the following example.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="@Model.VideoLink" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

See how you replace the frame source with the url from your model.

You may also need to add more data to your model to define other embedding options like allow full screen etc.

Comment: Lol now im getting big white spaces, the dimension for the video, but not the video itself, thanks though, clearly im doing something wrong...

Comment: In chrome console im getting this error: 
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WWzgGyAH6Y' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: Ok so go to YouTube and find the embed link of this video and just paste it in the view. This should show the video. Then replace the source with your stored url.

Comment: Try using another method for showing the video from the link I provided. Also you may need a special link for embedding the video so in that case you may need to do some string building to build the url from the video ID or even store the whole markup for embedding the video in the string property of your model.

Comment: just to be sure if im not making this wrong, in my view this is how im showing the link:

 <iframe src="@item.VideoLink" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Thanks for helping, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace **watch?v=** with **embed/**.
Just loop through video links(@links) and write this:-

```
<iframe src="@links.Replace("watch?v=", "embed/")" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```